# Sql query to check if a certain value appears more than once in rows

Tags: sql-server

I have table with 5 columns like this

```
+----+-------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
| Id |       CreateDate        | CompanyId | UserId | IsEnabled |
+----+-------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
|  1 | 2016-01-02 23:40:46.517 |         1 |      1 |         1 |
|  2 | 2016-01-16 00:07:59.857 |         1 |      2 |         1 |
|  3 | 2016-01-25 15:17:54.420 |         3 |      3 |         1 |
| 25 | 2016-03-07 16:48:39.260 |        24 |     10 |         0 |
| 26 | 2016-03-07 16:48:39.263 |        25 |      2 |         0 |
+----+-------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

(thanks http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html for ASCII table!)

I'm trying to check if a UserId is recorded for more than one CompanyId's.

So far I managed to check if a UserId happens to appear more than one by using this query

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT * ,
        Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId) as Cnt
        From CompanyUser
)

select Distinct UserId
FROM T
Where Cnt >1
```

It returns 2  correctly.

Where I'm stuck is, how can I parameterize the UserId and check if an Id is recorded for more than one company.

Comment: `select count(distinct companyid) from T where userid=@userid` ?

Comment: I tried that before and it gave an error, turns out I needed to start with a semicolon before the WITH. It works now Should have take my time and read the error description :)

Comment: @EgeBayrak no you don't need a semicolon to start a cte. You need to terminate the previous statement with a semicolon. It is however very common practice to start a cte with a semicolon. Eventually all statements will be required to be properly terminated. It is something that sql server has been very lax over since the beginning. There are a few statements like MERGE that require a semicolon at the end already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @UserID as bigint    
Set @UserID = 2

select Distinct Count(CompanyID)
FROM ComapynUser
Where UserId = @UserId
```

I think this gives you what you need.

Comment: Thank you, far simpler and far usefull than my struggle above